# Make Greasemonkey react to ajax change of an element

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

There is a page that loads with an empty span like this: `<span id="bla"></span>` and later fills that span with some text.

I need my script to get that text but Greasemonkey runs before it is filled with the text and even the `waitForKeyElements` function, that I tried to use, is not helping because the element is already there when the page loads.

Maybe I need in another way? Currently I am doing:

```
waitForKeyElements ("#bla", get_span_content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891), use the action-function's return value to fine tune the results.  If the span is **only filled/changed once,** the code would look like this:

```
 waitForKeyElements ("#bla", get_span_content);

 function get_span_content (jNode) {
     var spanText   = $.trim (jNode.text () );

     if (spanText == "") {
        //-- Still blank; tell waitForKeyElements to keep looking.
        return true;
     }
     else {
        //  DO WHATEVER WITH spanText HERE.
     }
}
```

---

If the *same* span is **changed multiple times**, the code would look like this:

```
 waitForKeyElements ("#bla", get_span_content);

 function get_span_content (jNode) {
     var spanText   = $.trim (jNode.text () );
     var lastText   = jNode.data ("lastText")  ||  "";

     if (spanText != lastText) {
         //  DO WHATEVER WITH spanText HERE.

         jNode.data ("lastText", spanText);
     }

     return true;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm. and also thanks for the better formatting in the question