# waitForKeyElements doesn't recognize selector, with "$"? On reload of same id?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

So I am trying to use the `waitForKeyElements()` function in order to detect AJAX content. 
The div I am trying to select has a "$" in its ID (e.g. `<div id="mydiv$0">`) and after much trial and error I am 90% sure it is causing a problem. The function just doesn't work. How would I fix this?

Also just a question regarding how the `waitForKeyElements()` function works. The site has a dropdown in which you select an option. Each option will load a table with the same ID's and classes, just different content.

Would the function recognize this new table loading?

Comment: `$("#\\$SomeId\\$OneMore\\$")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is two questions, in one.  The first was [answered by Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529570/331508); you must escape the `$` characters in the id.

So, for `<div id="mydiv$0">`, use something like:

```
waitForKeyElements ("#mydiv\\$0", yourActionFuntion);
```

The answer to the second question:

> Each option will load a table with the same ID's and classes, just
>   different content. Would the (waitForKeyElements) recognize this new
>   table loading?

is: **it depends.**

Is the page completely deleting and re-adding the element?  If so, then use `waitForKeyElements()` normally.

Is the page just changing the content of the element?  Then the best approach varies on the circumstances but, in general, use an approach similar to the second part of [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16169221/331508).

We need to see your target page, or [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), to say any more.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the dollar sign:

```
$('#mydiv\\$0')
```