# How to display a hidden element with Tampermonkey?

Tags: html, css, tampermonkey

I am struggling to get Tampermonkey (with Chrome) to automatically change the display style of a field on a website.
I would like to display the following hidden element:

```
<div class="VehicleDetailsPricing" id="VehicleDetailsPricing" style="display: none">
```

I can manually edit the the display style to `inline` which works, but cannot get Tampermonkey to do the same.

Comment: The element is probably added dynamically after the page has been loaded. See [Greasemonkey is unable to find/modify/delete content on Twitch.tv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298083)

Comment: @wOxxOm is correct, See the duplicate question. You could use something like: 
`waitForKeyElements ("#VehicleDetailsPricing", showInline);`

`function showInline (jN) { jN.css ("display", "inline"); }`